# Newrelic - Console Application and throughput

Tags: .net, console-application, newrelic

I'm trying to configure this long running application (Console application) with NewRelic. Purpose of the application is to read XML feed (lots and lots of data) and update database accordingly.

I want monitor its performance (which works great now) but also get emails if there are any issues (Errors).

1. I have customized my log4net adapter to use NewRelic API to `NotifyError`

This works fine and I can see errors logged in NewRelic, however Error % always shows 0 which means I never get any error alerts (even though there are many and my threshold is at 0.1%). I assume this is due to the fact that my Throughput is quite hight (23k  rpm).

Is there any way of adjusting how newrelic sees throughput to make my errors a bit more meaningful?

Comment: What do you mean by "many" here? If your throughput is 23K items per minute, how many of those are failing? If you're only getting (say) 2 failures per minute then that *is* below 0.1%. Perhaps you should try making your threshold 0% to start with, just to check that the alerts *can* get through at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi Jon, I'm not sure what throughput actually stands for in this particular application. All it does is goes over for loop and updates database. Is there anyway to control how throughput is calculated?

Comment: Well I would expect a 0.1% error rate to mean "more than 1 in 1000 operations fail". It's up to you how granular that is - is it in terms of "per item read within the XML feed" or something bigger?

Comment: @JonSkeet By operations you mean lines of code (except comments) or method calls? I just don't understand how this throughput calculated. It would be good to label a method with transaction argument. When it executes that's when its actually counted as a transaction. Are you aware of such thing?

Comment: No, I mean whatever you want to consider to be an operation. I haven't used NewRelic at all myself, but thinking in more general terms, if you want to be alerted if the "error rate" is above 0.1%, that needs to be a rate of failed operations to successful operations. Are you really just trying to find out how to report successful and failed operations in NewRelic? (It's not clear *exactly* what the question is.)

Comment: I log errors fine. Its just that throughput (being very large) makes errors insignificant.

Comment: But do you see what I mean by the rate needing to know the number of *successful* operations as well?

Comment: Yes I do understand that. I'm yet understand how throughput gets calculated.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way you could influence the throughput measurement. If the operations influencing your throughput are considered transactions by New Relic, you could use the API call IgnoreTransaction() to ignore all but the most significant transactions, including those that might throw the error you're flagging with NoticeError().

Comment: How do you define a transaction thought? Is it a line of code, a call to SQL? ... I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted NewRelic support and spoke to them directly. (They are very quick in replying and very helpful).

So (as per my conversation with New Relic Support);

> What is a request on standalone/background/console application?

Since you application is not making web calls it the two most likely candidates for "requests" would the the amount of XML sections being read and/or the number of database updates being pushed out. I am leaning toward the former since the database calls would likely get seen and placed under the database section.

> Is there a way of defining (via NR API or simply agent configuration) what should be counted as a transaction/request on standalone/background/console application?

I'm sorry, but there is no way to define or alter what is or is not a request, all of that is done automatically by the agent. All we can do is alter the name of a request inflight.

---

This means that (depends on what you application does), you might not be able to utilize Error Alerts efficiently, because ratio of errors to throughput is going to be very small. (Below 0% error rate) on standalone/background/console applications.